# Galaxy Nexus bluetooth keyboard connectbot

Tags: bluetooth

I have recently bought a Samsung Galaxy Nexus on which I use ConnectBot to connect to servers over ssh.

I have also bought a Apple bluetooth keyboard that I am currently using with the phone - and everything seems to be working properly.

However I encounter some problems when it comes to some of the 'special' keys on the keyboard like Tab and Esc.
Esc seems to be mapped to the 'back' key in Android. And Tab just doesn't seem to do what I want.

It's especially a problem when I'm editing files in vim and I try to exit insert mode... Then I am actually telling android to leave ConnectBot...

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use an onscreen keyboard, I've had a lot of luck with the [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsIm9yZy5wb2NrZXR3b3Jrc3RhdGlvbi5wY2tleWJvYXJkIl0.). It has the layout of a computer keyboard, including Esc, Tab, Alt, Ctrl, and various other keys which are usually missing from mobile keyboards.